# Multiple IF Create Element Javascript

Tags: javascript, createelement

Hi I am using createElement in javascript and I need it to be executed depends on the desired if.

I am using this code but without success.

What I need is:

That it is executed if it does not detect the value 2 in the variable typedelivery and then that it is executed if the value is less than 0 or null.

I have this code but I can't do it.

The first 2 parts work ie.

The code is not executed if it detects the value 2 in the variable typedelivery and if the value is less than or equal to 0 the element creator is executed.

But if the null variables this is not executed.

```
2 !== typedelivery && 0 >= parseInt(cargodelivery) && null !== parseInt(cargodelivery) &&
 myvar.createElement("span", { className: "gratuitoenvio font-size-sm mb-5 text-dark" }, "Envío Gratis"),
```

I also want it to run if the variable is null
But the second if cancels the next if by not finding the value less than 0 being null

Something similar to "??" in javascript create element

Comment: Share whole code html and JavaScript

Comment: Hello, For now I'm only creating that div with the javascript element creator, there is no more code and I can't get past that.

Comment: Why don't you use a normal `if` statement?

Comment: I need something like "??" from php

Comment: Also `null !== parseInt(cargodelivery)` will always be `true` because `parseInt` can never return `null`

Comment: I can't use the normal ifs with the element creator.
The ifs are based only on:
1 === myvar && or
1! == myvar && or
1 == myvar

Comment: Remove the parseInt and it doesn't work the same.
The if only goes up to step 2 and when it doesn't find a value it no longer continues to step 3 I need something like the "??" from PHP
That if you do not find value in step 2, skip to step 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt(null)` would return a `NaN` value, so you should either check for that, or check directly for a `null` value. Also, in most cases, you should check for `null` first.

```
2 !== typedelivery && (null == cargodelivery || 0 >= parseInt(cargodelivery)) &&
 myvar.createElement(...
```